# Selecionar colunas especificas de duas tabelas relacionas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma relação de N x 1, `Post x User`, têm uma relação como a seguinte:

Post.php (model):

```
....
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
....
```

O que eu quero é selecionar o `id` e o `username` do model `User` quando acedo aos `Post`, mas também quero selecionar apenas o `id` e `title` do model `Post` (não quero selecionar as colunas todas).

Com [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852927/get-specific-columns-using-with-function-in-laravel-eloquent):

```
return Post::with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->get();
```

Retorna sim o `id` e `username` do `User` de cada `Post`, para selecionar depois o `id` e o `title` do `Post` tentei:

```
return Post::with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->select(['id', 'title'])->get();
```

Porém sem sucesso, retornando o `User` a null. Estou a usar laravel 5.5, caso seja relevante.

**Nota:** Eu não quero nada 'hard coded' no ficheiro dos models, porque eu posso querer diferentes colunas em diferentes situções, de preferência gostava mesmo que a relação declarada em `Post.php` se mantivesse.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste com uma situação parecida e seu código está correto. Qual o erro, está retornando `null`?

Comment: O 'erro', é quando tento selecionar também só algumas colunas só algumas colunas do post @AndréLuizdeGusmão . No meu segundo cenário o `id` e o `title` retornam corretamente mas o user fica a null

Comment: Você pode postar os dois `Models` e as duas tabelas?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não há muito mais nos meus models. Isto é para uma resposta json (caso se relevante), não estou a usar blade.

Comment: @HulaHula eu sei o problema estou passando em uma resposta ja ja está pronta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É o seguinte, quando o [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) faz a relação e carrega o relacionamento, a chaves que se relacionam deve estar contidas no resultados da [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), porque, esses valores são utilizados para carregar os relacionamentos, e pelo visto na sua pergunta isso foi suprimido, ou seja, a chave não foi mencionada na [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) e isso acarreta a não trazer os dados da relação, um exemplo em [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) para você ter uma idéia do funcionamento do mesmo, ***exemplo***:

```
Post::with('user')->get();
```

esse comando gera uma SQL assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`
```

no resultado dessa `SQL` traz todos os campos `user_id` (nomenclatura padrão do `Eloquent`) com esses valores e executa mais uma `SQL`

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id IN [aqui todos os valores de `user_id`]
```

como na sua pergunta não a chave então não vai mostrar nada inclusive não consegue após isso fazer a correlação com os resultados da primeira `SQL`.

### A solução

Passe a chave no `select` de `Post`, ***exemplo***:

```
return Post::with(array('user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}))->select(['id', 'title', 'user_id'])->get();
```

Usando o [tinker](https://github.com/laravel/tinker) o resultado disso tudo foi o que está explicado:

```
>>> App\Models\Post::with(['user' => function($q) { 
      return $q->select('id','name');}]
    )->select('id','title','user_id')->get();

string(44) "select `id`, `title`, `user_id` from `posts`"
array(0) { }
string(61) "select `id`, `name` from `users` where `users`.`id` in (?, ?)"
array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Laravel - tinker](https://github.com/laravel/tinker)
- [Laravel - Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)
- [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

Comment: Virgilio obrigado. Era isso mesmo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045440/select-specific-collumns-from-both-related-tables-models?noredirect=1#comment81038448_47045440 :P

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz o teste com um relacionamento 1xN para simular o seu problema e acredito que o seu código está correto. Falta apenas inserir a chave estrangeira do relacionamento.

Eu faria uma modificação nos arrays também

```
Post::with(['user'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id','username');
}])->select('id', 'title', 'user_id')->get();
```

Uma outra alternativa que você pode escolher é criar a consulta através da classe `DB`. Digamos que a classe `Post` seja relativo a tabela `posts` e a classe `User` seja relativo a tabela `users`, você pode escrever a mesma `query` acima assim:

```
DB::table('posts')
    ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('users.id as user_id', 'users.username', 'posts.id as post_id', 'posts.title')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas era preciso selecionar o `user_id` também do model `Post`, fica +1 pela segunda segunda solução

Comment: Mas tem os dois ids na solução que eu postei, o do post `post_id` e o do user `user_id`.

Comment: Tem na segunda alternativa, mas prefiro usar eloquent sempre que possível

Comment: @AndréLuizdeGusmão o seu primeiro código tem que ter a chave que corresponde a relação de Post com User, é por isso que não consegue trazer as informações no seu código está igual da pergunta e não é a solução, o segundo não é o que ele quer, mas, é uma opção boa. Só estou dizendo isso para você colocar a chave restante, porque, se não a resposta de certo modo está errada. Além da minha resposta tem um link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045440/select-specific-collumns-from-both-related-tables-models?noredirect=1#comment81038448_47045440 que também diz a mesma coisa no SOEn

Comment: Pronto @VirgilioNovic, concordo com você, assim outras pessoas que acessarem vão poder ver apenas respostas corretas.

Comment: @AndreGusmao o problema são aqueles que vão te dar votos negativos ... para mim esses são os que você tem que ficar atento.